# Cambiar de color en un TexView según el valor en Android Studio

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, json

Buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto de la escuela y quisiera saber si hay algún método de cambiar un color dentro de un TextView desde Android Studio con los datos obtenidos en MySql, ya he obtenido los datos con PHP y me muestra en un TextView, pero ahora quiero que cuando se inserte otro tipo de datos me cambie de color, por ejemplo el valor = 50 es verde, cuando se muestra el valor = 100 debe cambiarme a rojo. He investigado que se podía con PHP pero no logro que esto se vea en mi aplicación Android Studio, les comparto el código de la obtención de datos:

```
public void obtenerData() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("datos");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String auxId = jsonObject1.getString("id");
                                String auxValor = jsonObject1.getString("valor");
                                listaDatos.add(new Datos(auxId, auxValor));
                            }
                            AdapterDatos adaptador = new AdapterDatos(listaDatos);
                            rvDatos.setAdapter(adaptador);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suponiendo que ya tienes declarados tus TextView, dentro de la función **onResponse** debes asignarle la propiedad **setBackgroundColor**. Debes verificar el valor que obtienes desde la respuesta de tu servidor y dependiendo el valor le asignas el color.

Por ejemplo:

```
    String auxValor = jsonObject1.getString("valor");

    if(!auxValor.isEmpty() && auxValor.equals("50")){
    textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));
    }
```

Comment: Excelente me ha funcionado! gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Que tal disculpa que aproveche la respuesta estoy haciendo algo similar solo que conmigo yo no obtengo un valor si no un mensaje en este caso como podria implementarlo mis valor a recibir son `Certificacion Vencida` , `Certificacion Vigente` , `Certificacion a x dias de vencer`. use el mismo que en la respuesta pero me arroja null por que no recibe un valor como tal